# spring mongoDB aggregation with sort doesn't work

Tags: spring, mongodb, sorting, aggregation

I'm trying to combine aggregation with sort operation in my program, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
GroupOperation groupByDate = Aggregation.group("resetDateTime").push("$$ROOT").as("resetDataList");
MatchOperation untilDate = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("resetDateTime").lte(LocalDateTime.of(startDate.toLocalDate(), LocalTime.MAX)));
MatchOperation relevantId = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("id").is(id));
SortOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "resetDateTime");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(relevantId , untilDate, sort, groupByDate);
```

both putting the **"sort"** parameter before and after the **"groupByDate"** parameter does not work.
The output is not sorted.
Does anyone know why is it not working?

this is the output of the aggregation operation without sort parameter (I printed to **"dateTime"** field of each group:

> [ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-14T17:37:35.044),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-13T17:37:35.015),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-12T17:37:35.942),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-03T17:37:35.137),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-11T17:37:35.885),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-07T17:37:35.624),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-09T17:37:35.737),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-02T17:37:35.096),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-01T17:37:35.826),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-10T17:37:35.834),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-15T17:37:35.106),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-05T17:37:35.350),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-04T17:37:35.193),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-06T17:37:35.397),
>   ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-08T17:37:35.706)]

Comment: What is the output (show a sample document) after the "groupByDate" stage; _without_ applying the "sort" stage.

Comment: hi, I added the output in the question body. thanks! @prasad_

Comment: You have to post the output with the fields names and all.

Comment: done, I hope this is more helpull @prasad_

Comment: The document format is: `ResetDataGroupByDate(resetDateTime=2019-10-14T17:37:35.044)`. I think, applying sort on the date field need to be like this: `SortOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "resetDateTime");` -or- `SortOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "ResetDataGroupByDate.resetDateTime");`.

Comment: ``SortOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "resetDateTime");`` generates the same output. like no sort is being performed.

Comment: the second option you suggested sadly generated a "illegal argument" exception):

Comment: Did you apply the sort after the group or before?

Comment: both before and after. both times the output is unsorted

Comment: Post a _sample document_ (with fields you are using in the application) from the collection you are performing the aggregation on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204724/discussion-between-rotem-linik-and-prasad).

Answer (score 0):

After group, the field resetDateTime is id field for next pipeline so your sort should be on id field and not on resetDateTime.

```
SortOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "_id");
```